# chunked file uploads in django

Tags: python, django, nginx

I need to get chunked file uploads working in my django app (with nginx/uwsgi in front on multiple load-balanced EC2 instances with no shared storage).  It seems like a combination of https://github.com/juliomalegria/django-chunked-upload and https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload would be ideal, but this django package seems to want to use a model/db to store the file objects and my application does not use models or a db at all (and needs to stay that way).

What is a good alternative to get chunked file uploads working?

Comment: Are you trying to upload the files to s3?

Comment: No, the files will be sent on to a backend service.